# How can Socket object be made with ServerSocket's method accept()?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

After finishing `I/O streams` and `Concurrency` I decided to learn `Socket programming`. So far I made a simple **Server-Client**. But I have a little question about understanding how are *Socket objects actually made*. Hope someone can make an easy explanation, as I am new to this.

The basic rule I follow is to make `Socket` by providing both **IP Address** and **Port number**. So I would do something like:

```
Socket s = new Socket(StringIP, intPort);
```

But I also came across the thing that confuses me, and that is using `accept()` from *ServerSocket's class*.

```
ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(portNum);
Socket socket = myServer.accept();
```

Doc says it returns new Socket after a connection is made. Fair enough. But how can it know the client's port and IP? Does it mean that the variable *socket* has all the data about the client (meaning on its IP and port)? If so, how can it know it, without me manually putting it in the constructor as I showed in the first example? Can someone tell me what am I missing so I can move on?

Comment: Why are you concerned with the client's port or IP? The port used is the same as the server socket. What would you do with the IP if you had it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels True, this comment kind of opened my eyes. But technically it does have its IP address and port when Socket is made this way, does it?

Comment: A socket is for communicating pure and simple. If information needs to be shared, then pass directly over the socket that which needs to be shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can it know the client's port and IP?

The client port and IP are in the network packets.  The operating system picks up and records this information, and passes it on to Java via the results (loosely speaking) of syscalls.  This is all done under the hood in JVM native code.  (And the OS kernel, of course.)

If you really need to understand exactly how this happens, it will all be clear in the OpenJDK source code (which is freely downloadable).  But you would need to be able to read and search C and C++ code to figure it out.